# how to use in fuction varible inside value in document.ready...?

Tags: function, cordova, variables, document-ready

chanter in this variable my value but how to use this chanter variable value outside function means document.ready..?
but my alert give me undefined so help me please....?
in function (querySuccessDefaultChanter) chanter give me value but i want to pass that value in searchQolo

```
<script>
var chanter;

    function GetDefaultChanter(){
            db.transaction(function (tx){
                tx.executeSql('SELECT Value FROM Setting where Key = "DefaultChanter";',[],querySuccessDefaultChanter);},                         
                errorCB);
        }


    function querySuccessDefaultChanter(tx,result){
                $.each(result.rows,function(index){
                    var row = result.rows.item(index);
                    chanter = row["Value"];
                });
            }

$(document).ready(function (e) {

GetDefaultChanter();
alert(chanter);
searchQolo(term,type,chanter);      

});

</script>
```

Comment: declare this variable outside method body. You can access it anywhere in the document.

Comment: @MehmoodMemon sir please check my code

Comment: Still not working ??

Comment: where have you declared 'term', 'type' ?

Comment: @MehmoodMemon sir just u tell me how pass my function variable in searchQolo. term And Type is passed and i Got Both Value But Not Pass chanter Variable value in searchQolo

Comment: Check my answer. Tell me if there is still some problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, document.ready function is executed before every other function, you will always get chanter as undefined. One way is that you can call searchQolo function after chanter value is assigned inside querySuccessDefaultChanter function. Try this.

```
<script>
var chanter;

    function GetDefaultChanter(){
            db.transaction(function (tx){
                tx.executeSql('SELECT Value FROM Setting where Key = "DefaultChanter";',[],querySuccessDefaultChanter);},                         
                errorCB);
        }


    function querySuccessDefaultChanter(tx,result){
         $.each(result.rows,function(index){
               var row = result.rows.item(index);
               chanter = row["Value"];
         });
         alert(chanter);
         searchQolo(term,type,chanter);
    }

$(document).ready(function (e) {
   GetDefaultChanter();
});

</script>
```